# Better way to search a list of lists for an item in python

Tags: java, python, for-loop, foreach

Sometimes I have a list of lists, and I need to search all the lists for a single item.  I use this python code:

```
boolean found = false

for(hayStack : listOfHayStacks){
   found = findNeedle(hayStack)

   if(found)
      break;
}

if(!found){
    // error case
}
```

I seem to run into this sort of case frequently and I always felt like there should be a better way of handling this.

Is there an: "atLeastOne" construction that sums up all the results?

Comment: I run into this frequently and I use the same exact way you do. If there is a better way here, I'd love to know also. Though what do you mean by "atLeastOne" construction?

Comment: In Perl: `warn "Didn't find a needle." unless any { findNeedle($_) } @listOfHayStacks;`  If your language of preference supports some form of lambda expressions you can create a similar construct.  But the underlying algorithm is the same; iterate through each element, call findNeedle, stop looking as soon as one is found, and deal with an error if none is found.

Comment: Calpis :: (from FogleBird's answer) looks like python has an "any" construction that you can combine with list comprehension to bulk test the resulting booleans.

Comment: This isn't an algorithm question, and the answer depends on the programming language or paradigm. Functional languages generally have a find function that yields the first item found in any sort of collection. They also provide for invoking two different functional expressions (lambda functions) depending on whether the value was found. But you formulated your question imperatively and that's the sort of answer most people give will give.

Comment: @JimBalter I probably could have put the question better, but I was hoping for something that was in fact language agnostic (a way to rewrite the problem differently).  From the answers below, Python definitely supports the functional/lambda expressions, but Java probably lacks it (at least until it gains lambda support)

Comment: Python has rudimentary functional facilities, but you should take a look at functional languages like Haskell, F#, or Scala. You might be stunned at how much can be said elegantly without any loops or "for ... in ..." constructs. Something like haystacks.foreach.find(needle).optional({function to perform on needle if found})

Comment: P.S. It makes no sense to ask for a language agnostic construction. Some languages don't even have a break statement. The most language *independent* solution you're likely to find is vlad's suggestion. But the answer you accepted uses a Python-specific feature with no equivalent in most languages. In fact it offers two different Python solutions, both of which are idiosyncratic, the first even more than the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has special syntax for this.

```
for haystack in haystacks:
    if find_needle(haystack):
        break
else:
    # error case (did not break)
```

Depending on how much logic you need in your code, you could also do something like this:

```
some_needles_exist = any(find_needle(x) for x in haystacks)
all_stacks_have_needles = all(find_needle(x) for x in haystacks)
```

Comment: Beat me.  I often use the pattern `any(val in stack for stack in stacks)` when short-circuiting matters and `find_needle(x)` is simply testing membership in a collection.

Comment: Anyone know if there is a way  with the "any" and list comprehension to stop on the first?  If find_needle() is expensive and I just want the first one, it would be nice not to have to go over the entire list of haystacks if it's not needed.

Comment: @Mark: `any` does short-circuit. Why did you think it doesn't?

Comment: Ah! You are right! I apparently looked at the wrong doc section

Answer (score 0):

you can always create a separate function in which you use a double for loop. It might be a bit more readable:

```
for (hayStack : listOfHayStacks) {
    for (needle : hayStack) {
        if needle satisfies criteria
            return true
    }
}
return false
```

the problem with searching all haystacks is that you're potentially wasting a lot of time, if you could have returned in the first few haystacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to concentrate more on the actions done on finding or not finding the needle in a haystack then you could do this sort of thing:

```
>>> criteria = lambda n: n == 3
>>> def found(needle):
    if criteria(needle):
        print("Doing something as found")
        return True
    else: return False


>>> def missed():
    print("Doing missed action")
    return False

>>> wasfound = any(found(i) for i in range(2)) or missed()
Doing missed action
>>> wasfound
False
>>> wasfound = any(found(i) for i in range(4)) or missed()
Doing something as found
>>> wasfound
True
>>>
```